# Ctrl-W in insert mode erases only up to where insert was started

Tags: insert-mode

I frequently use `<C-w>` in insert mode to back up when I mistype things. I've noticed some odd behavior if I start insert mode when in the middle of  a word.

For example, if I have the following line (cursor location indicated by `^`):

```
I love to use CamelCase
                   ^
```

When I am at that cursor location and do the key combination `i<End><C-w>`, I am left with the following:

```
I love to use Camel
                   ^
```

I expected that `<C-w>` would erase up to the beginning of `CamelCase` since that is a word. Is `<C-w>` only supposed to erase up to the beginning of where I started inserting? Or is there some setting I have to flip to get it to delete the entire word?

If I press `<C-w>` again, it does erase the rest of the word. I just wasn't expecting a word boundary to appear where insert mode started.

This is using Vim 8.1 (2018 May 18) for Windows.

Comment: The same issue happens for `<c-u>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is documented behaviour. Deleting text before the insert start location is controlled by the 'backspace' option, and [:help 'backspace'](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27backspace%27) says this:

> start: allow backspacing over the start of insert; CTRL-W and CTRL-U stop once at the start of insert.

---

If you really want `<C-w>` to behave as you "expect", here's a convoluted mapping (the different handling depending on whether the cursor is at the end of the line or not is to make sure that the last character is handled correctly: if you do `db` when the cursor is at the end of the line, the last character is not deleted; if you do `vbd` when the cursor is *not* at the end of the line, the following character is deleted):

```
inoremap <expr> <C-w> col('.') == len(getline('.'))+1 ? "\<C-o>vb\"_d" : "\<C-o>\"_db"
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Vim patch [8.2.0590](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/aa0489e12d227d24752cf16e4e97058ac32edcc1) you can use `:set backspace+=nostop` to make backspace and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> *not* stop at the insertion point.

Comment: Great! I missed that one.

Answer (score 1):

An easier remap for `<c-w>` is:

```
ino <c-w> <c-\><c-o>i<c-w>
```

Note that this also moves the insert start location, which may changes the behavior of `<c-u>` or `<bs>` (depends on `'backspace'` option)